# Mysql select query, splitting column data conditionally into 2 new columns

Tags: mysql, select, group-by

I have a table called credit_log and the columns are

```
user_id | amount
```

The amount can be positive or negative. Positive means credits bought, negative means credits  spent.
So, I want to have a query which returns

```
user_id | Bought | Spent
```

essentially , i want to sum up positive amount values in to Bought and sum up negative amount in to Spent and I want to group by the user_id

Currently I have a query like this

```
select user_id,sum(amount) from credit_log group by user_id;
```

but it sums up both positive and negative values. How can I write a query to separate them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some conditional statements inside the query should work nicely:

```
SELECT
    user_id,
    SUM(IF(amount > 0, amount, 0)) bought,
    SUM(IF(amount < 0, amount, 0)) spent
FROM credit_log
GROUP BY user_id;
```

Comment: @JYelton so you posted while I was writing mine. Didn't realize you posted.

Comment: Usually SO tries to be helpful with a JS banner that lets you know something's been posted, but if posts are seconds apart that isn't usually enough warning.

Answer (score 1):

```
 select user_id, sum(if(amount>0,amount,0)) bought, sum(if(amount<0,amount,0)) spent
 from web_user_credits group by user_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% the syntax is the same in mysql... but it looks like it:

```
select
  user_id
 ,case when amount > 0 then amount else 0 end as bought
 ,case when amount < 0 then amount else 0 end as spent
from
 credit_log
```

And you can go on to simply place `sum()` around the case statements (include the `end` but not `as`).

Answer (score 0):

check this :

```
select user_id , sum(if(amount< 0 ,0 ,amount )) as spent, 
    sum(if(amount> 0 ,0 ,amount )) as bought
from  credit_log  group by  user_id
```